# Is there any REST API present on Keycloak to manage account details of individual user without admin api/account?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

From Keycloak UI, I am able to edit the account information of the user using `{keycloak_server_address}/auth/realms/NTC/account/` link.

[image]

I am aware of update user admin API to edit user information. Is there any way to edit user information by the user itself with manage-account privilege?

Answer (score 1):

We required this functionality and we ended up creating our own REST API.

We have Keycloak admin credentials in configuration file and when user calls our method we create request to Keycloak API with admin credentials. We use JWT token authentication in our API and check prefered_username claim.

It is not a simple solution, but if you realy need it I guess it is only way to do it.